# can't float inside div with position fixed

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

http://jsfiddle.net/1351qL91/

```
<div style="width:200px"> 
<span style="float:left">left</span>
<span style="float:right">right</span>
<br/>
<div style="position:relative">
    <span style="float:left">left</span>
    <span style="float:right">right</span>
<div>
<br/>
<div style="position:fixed"> 
    <span style="float:left">left</span>
    <span style="float:right">right</span>
</div>
```

spans with float right won't float right inside a div with position fixed.

I came to the conclusion that float won't work if the container's width is 
unknown, and in this case the width is indeed unknown.

So another question which may solve this problem is how to set a fixed position child to 100% width of it's parent?

P.S I'm using bootstrap 3, which means the container div (which I set to 200px) is actually of class col-md-3 -> I don't know the width of the container, that's why I need it to be dynamic

Comment: width:100% will take up all the space, beyond the limits of the container

Comment: >fixed The element is positioned relative to the browser window. Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: hope its working in bootstrap https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8322/

Comment: @Amit your jsfiddle doesn't work...

Comment: then update your demo with relevant bootstrap code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Floating wont work inside `fixed` or `absolute` divs unless you specify `width`.

You cannot use `position:fixed` to position inside the bootstrap grid. Fixed positioned divs are relative to the browser. You need to use `absolute` positioning.

Comment: OK, so no float... I'll figure out another solution. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 4):

How you want to float a div inside another if you don't have a width? You can use with %:

```html
<div style="position:fixed; border:solid 1px #c1c1c1; width: 100%;"> 
    <span style="float:left">left</span>
    <span style="float:right">right</span>
</div>
```

Or, you can define a width to the div's inside:

```html
<div style="position:fixed; border:solid 1px #c1c1c1;"> 
  <span style="float:left; width:150px;">left</span>
  <span style="float:right; width:150px;">right</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 3, which means the container div (which I set to 200px) is actually of class col-md-3 -> I don't know the width of the container, that's why I need it to be dynamic

Comment: How odedta said, the fixed position is relative to the browser. You must to use fixed position?

Comment: Yes - I wanted a fixed position side bar, with content floating to the left and to the right inside it.
But I guess I'll have to find a different solution (since I don't want to calculate the width using js)

Comment: You can try min-width and max-width in the div with fixed position. So the width will be dinamic, but with limits.

Answer (score 1):

A fixed position element is positioned **relative** to the viewport, or the browser window itself.so when you give width:100% it takes up all the space in your viewport.

If you are using jquery there are plugins available that can be used to create a fixed postion side bar.
Examples:

- http://www.berriart.com/sidr/#getstarted
- http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/sticky-sidebar/

Answer (score 0):

A JQuery solution i used for this problem:

-Modified html

```
<div id="firstDiv style="width:200px"> 
<span style="float:left">left</span>
<span style="float:right">right</span>
<br/>
<div style="position:relative">
    <span style="float:left">left</span>
    <span style="float:right">right</span>
<div>
<br/>
<div id="fixed" style="position:fixed"> 
    <span style="float:left">left</span>
    <span style="float:right">right</span>
</div>
```

-JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#fixed').width($('#firstDiv').width());
});

$( window ).resize(function()
{
    $('#fixed').width($('#firstDiv').width());
});
```

And here your changed [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1351qL91/45/)